# Check if config map or secret is used?

Tags: kubernetes

Using kubectl or the Azure Kubernetes Services portal, how can I check whether a certain config map or secret is used by any resources?

Answer (score 3):

They can appear in (at least) 3 locations that I know of:

- as volumes
- in `env:` via `valueFrom:`
- in `envFrom:`

then, they can appear in both currently running pods, as well as "future pod" definitions such as CronJob or scaled down Deployment, StatefulSet, or even DaemonSets that don't match any current Nodes

This answer will focus on just the currently running pods, because it's less text to put into SO, but introspecting the other resource types are similar in concept. This will also only focus on `containers[]` although `initContainers[]` are also candidates but share the structure with `container[]` so are textually similar

Then, the worst possible case are the ones that are referenced via any Custom Resource Definition objects that may be in use in your cluster, and I don't believe it's possible to find those in the general case

#### volume references

```bash
kubectl get po -A -o json | \
  jq '.items[].spec.volumes[] as $v | select($v.configMap) | $v.configMap.name'
```

substituting `.secret` to find references to `Secret`s

#### env values

```bash
kubectl get po -A -o json | \
  jq '.items[].spec.containers[] as $c
    | select($c.env) | $c.env[] as $e
    | select($e.valueFrom.configMapKeyRef) | $e.valueFrom.configMapKeyRef.name'
```

#### envFrom references

```bash
kubectl get po -A -o json | \
  jq '.items[].spec.containers[] as $c 
    | select($c.envFrom) | $c.envFrom[] as $e 
    | select($e.configMapRef) | $e.configMapRef.name'
```

*I'll leave this as a Community Wiki so others can weigh in if I've overlooked some*